# How to get status of congestionprovider option in Windows Vista & Windows 7?

Tags: windows, performance, tcp, bandwidth, utilization

Congestion provider is new service in Windows Vista (i assume Windows 7 contains it too) for squeezing more from your network bandwidth available. It applies only for applications using tcp protocol. The principle behind this is that winsock implementation can change TCP window size more aggresively with changing transfer conditions. These conditions are for example current network load and delay. Delay is measured as round-trip-time. Its time needed for signal to travel back and forth (because TCP is reliable protocol as opposed to UDP it must acknowledge successfull receiving of packet or block of packets). More info about this matter is in article on technet:
http://technet.microsoft.com/sk-sk/magazine/2007.01.cableguy(en-us).aspx

Congestion provider service is by default disabled in Windows Vista. It can be enabled by following command:

```
netsh interface tcp set global congestionprovider=ctcp
```

I havent found command for getting its actual state. I need it to be sure that new option is active after system restart. Also don't know state of this service in Windows 7.

Comment: I will answer my question.
Go to a command prompt and type netsh (enter), interface (enter), tcp (enter), and show global (enter).  You should see something similar to this:
TCP Global Parameters
Receive Side Stealing State                     : enabled
Chimney Offload State                           : enabled
Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level                : normal
Add-On Congestion Control Provider              : none
ECN Capability                                  : disabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                             : disabled

Comment: Command can be typed also in one step: "netsh interface tcp show global".

Answer (score -1):

You should:

1. open notepad and copy this:

   > Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
   >
   > [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro
   >   l\Nsi{eb004a03-9b1a-11d4-9123-0050047759bc}\0]
   >   "0200"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,
   >   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
   >   00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
   >   ,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,​\
   >   00,00,00,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
   >   ,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,​\
   >   ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
   >   "1700"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,
   >   00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
   >   00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
   >   ,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,​\
   >   00,00,00,ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
   >   ,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,​\
   >   ff,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
2. close the notepad then click save and then name it the file as enable-esn-ctcp.reg and on the encoding option you will see the option is set to ASNI change that to unicode and save
3. double click the file or import it to your registry then restart your computer
4. finally type `netsh int tcp show global` on an elevated or administrator cmd done this option applies to windows 8

Comment: First of all, this question was asked three years ago. Second, Blindly setting control sets to pastes one finds on the internet is... frankly, not very smart, and I sincerely hope nobody does that. Even if this might indeed be the solution.